# Rails 4.2: Getting "Unpermitted parameters" on user creation after adding `protected_attributes` gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

I am upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.2 and wanted to follow Ryan Bates' advice of getting things working as quickly as possible before doing any major refactoring.

To that end, I installed the `protected_attributes` gem because I was under the impression that with this gem installed I wouldn't need to implement the strong params approach in my controllers immediately and could continue using `attr_accessible` in the models until I have time to refactor.

I'm not getting any errors about `attr_accessible` itself, but when I try to create a user in development I get `Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name, phone` despite having all of those as arguments in the User model's `attr_accessible` method.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: Sort of. I ended up just starting the process of switching over to using strong params in my controllers where necessary. I still am not sure how or if it's possible to do what I was trying to do (utilize only `attr_accessible` from the models in Rails 4).

Answer (score 2):

That's not the correct approach. Instead of porting a legacy, deprecated feature from 3.2 to 4.2, what you really want to do instead is the opposite: install [`strong_parameters`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem in Rails 3.2 and make sure to replace the `attr_accessible` before the upgrade.

Rails 4.x is not really designed to use protected attributes anymore, therefore you will encounter a lot of issues trying to reintroduce it.

Comment: I see. I was following the Railscast about upgrading to Rails 4 and it goes through the upgrade, then adds that gem, then sets about to using the method outlined in Andrey Deineko's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use strong params you will have to update your controller's code (which is what I recommend to do, since it won't cost too much work).

In general the implementation of using [`strong_parameters`](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) is as follows:

```
  def create
    @model = Model.create(model_params)
    if @model.persisted?
      # logic
    else
      #logic
    end
  end

private

def model_params
  params.require(:model).permit(:model_attrbite1, :model_attribute2)
end
```